# How do I reduce the quality of UIImage without reducing the resolution?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an upload limit of 2 MB with my images. So if a user tries to upload an image bigger then 2 MB, I would like to reduce it's size without reducing the resolution.

How do I achieve that? I tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
        var fileSize = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)!.length
        print("before File size:")
        print(fileSize)

        while fileSize > MyConstants.MAX_ATTACHMENT_SIZE{

            let mydata = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.75)
            fileSize = mydata!.length
            image = UIImage(data: mydata!)!

            print("make smaller \(fileSize)")
        }

        print("after File size:")
        print(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)!.length)
```

output:

```
before File size:
2298429
make smaller 846683
after File size:
2737491
```

Comment: Why did you use while loop ? You can use if()

Comment: the while loop will recursively create an image with quality at 0.75 unlike an if condition

Answer (score -1):

```
  let mydata = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.75)
        fileSize = mydata!.length
        image = UIImage(data: mydata!)!
```

This is the right approach. You can set different scale from `0.1 to 1` that how much you want to reduce the quality and size of the image.

`print(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)!.length)` this line again increase image's quality and size or resolution to maximum `(because scale = 1)`

Comment: the update adds nothing new, it's the same as what I have stated in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

As @Lion said, you will have to play around with the quality to achieve an agreeable file size. I noticed however that:

```
print(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)!.length)
```

Will print the image length at max quality. This is misleading since inside the while condition, you are achieving smaller file size.

```
while fileSize > MyConstants.MAX_ATTACHMENT_SIZE{

            let mydata = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.75)
            fileSize = mydata!.length
            image = UIImage(data: mydata!)!

            print("make smaller \(fileSize)")
        }
```

Comment: I notice that, but when I do set image with new small mydata, will it not be smaller as well?

Comment: Yes, it will be. Its a catch 22 as you will have to reach a compromise somewhere that satisfies your implementation. You could explore the [UIImage imageWithData:scale:] method equivalent in Swift.

Comment: Whoever down voted, would be nice to add a reason than hide eh?